# what is the equivalent code in c#

Tags: c#

My.Computer.Audio.Play(strAudioFilePath, AudioPlayMode.Background)

This is vb.net code i want to write similar code in c#. i tried converting this code in c# but it is not working, does anyone have have any idea?

Comment: Did you try to google it? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y171b18.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(strAudioFilePath);
simpleSound.Play();
```

Comment: MSDN link to SoundPlayer class... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx

Answer (score 6):

You will have to Add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic for an exactly equivalent code like this.

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.Audio audio = new Audio();
audio.Play(strAudioFilePath, AudioPlayMode.Background);
```

Although there are other options which don't involve `Audio` class.

Comment: While I'm sure this works, it would be better to avoid using the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace if you're switching to C#.

Comment: Yes, but he was asking for equivalent code so I gave him an exactly equivalent code :)

Comment: The Microsoft.VisualBasic is perfectly valid in C# though - It's a .net Assembly, just like all the other ones, and it does offer some nice functionality.